# session-like request with Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, python-requests

I was trying to scrape data from this [website](http://directoriosancionados.funcionpublica.gob.mx/SanFicTec/jsp/Ficha_Tecnica/SancionadosN.jsp?cmdsan=ALL&tipoqry=ALL&mostrar_msg=SI). I need to click on each company name and then extract the data that appears on the right. I couldn't achieve it with normal request, had to use session to manage cookies. With requests and BeautifulSoup I would do it this way

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

start_url = r"http://directoriosancionados.funcionpublica.gob.mx/SanFicTec/jsp/Ficha_Tecnica/SancionadosN.jsp?cmdsan=ALL&tipoqry=ALL&mostrar_msg=SI"

s = requests.Session()
response=s.post(start_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
links = soup.find_all("a", {"onclick":pattern})
onclicks = [link["onclick"] for link in links]
for element in onclicks[:10]:
    expe = re.search(string=element, pattern=r"\d+/\d+").group(0)
    r = s.post(url="http://directoriosancionados.funcionpublica.gob.mx/SanFicTec/jsp/Ficha_Tecnica/FichaSinTabla.jsp",
      data={"expe":expe,
              "tipo":"1",
              "persona":"3"}).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
    something = soup.find("p", {"class":"normal"})
    print(something)
```

Now I am wondering if something like that would be possible in scrapy:

```
class Spider:
    def get_expe():
        #get the list of expe

    def make_requests():
        #use the same session and make post requests for each expe

    def parse():
        #extract the data
```

Of course I am not expecting you to write the spider for me. Any help to figure out how to use the same cookie in the session would be appreiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need any special cookies handling here on top of what Scrapy provides by default. Look at the minimal working example for your scenario:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import scrapy


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example'
    start_urls = ['http://directoriosancionados.funcionpublica.gob.mx/SanFicTec/jsp/Ficha_Tecnica/SancionadosN.jsp?cmdsan=ALL&tipoqry=ALL&mostrar_msg=SI/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.xpath('//table//tr//a'):
            data = {
                'expe': link.xpath('./@onclick').re_first(r'\d+/\d+'),
                'tipo': '1',
                'persona': '3'
            }
            yield scrapy.FormRequest('http://directoriosancionados.funcionpublica.gob.mx/SanFicTec/jsp/Ficha_Tecnica/FichaSinTabla.jsp',
                                     formdata=data, callback=self.parse_detail)

    def parse_detail(self, response):
        yield {
            'infractor': response.xpath('(//p[@class="normal"])[1]/text()').extract_first()
        }
```

Comment: Yes, it does work. Scrapy is smarter than I thought. Thanks!